# Edit node as text link in Twig

Tags: theming, 8

How to write the same code in Twig?

```
<?php print l(t('Edit this node'), 'node/' . $entity->nid . '/edit'); ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this example from [Functions - In Twig Templates](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/functions-in-twig-templates):

```
{# Link to node page. #}
<a href="{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': node.id}) }}">{{ 'View node page'|t }}</a>
```

in which you need to use the route to edit the node: `entity.node.edit_form`